# NetBeans: change compiler/linker parameters with command line

Tags: bash, gcc, netbeans, makefile, toolchain

I want to change the compiler/linker parameters without using NetBeans GUI, i.e. I want every new project I make has already set gcc parameters (like -I and -l -L) in makefile without enter in the project properties window by user interface. I need it for an installation script which already set netbeans for working with fixed library (for example openCV) at first boot. I already tried changing toolchain file like GNU_c.xml and GNU_cpp.xml but without results. Same thing making a GCC alias/bash function before starting netbeans (no inerithance between subshell that netbeans creates for compiling/linking files), also modifying .bashrc file with alias same results.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could define an alias in your `.bashrc`, for example :

```
$ echo "alias gcc='gcc -l -Wall -Wextra" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

In the case of NetBeans, I don't know if it launches an instance of bash to run gcc but if not, you could define a script as an executable that contains something like (for example):

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -l -Wall -Wextra "$@"
# or [gcc "$@"] only if you have define the previous alias in your bashrc
```

Comment: I have already tried to modify bashrc but doesn't work; 
the second method it's not the case; netbeans doen't seem to lunch a script to execute make command.

Comment: I don't really know NetBeans but I would be surprised if it's not possible. With eclipse in any case, it's possible.